# Wordpress: Using pre_get_posts to for ordering search results

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to order by postmeta `total_sales`

```
function ta_modify_main_query($query) {
   if ($query->is_search()) {
       $query->set('orderby', 'meta_value_num');
       $query->set('meta_key', 'total_sales');
       $query->set('order', 'DESC');
   }
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'ta_modify_main_query', 999 );
```

I think the code is good, but it does not work, the query is not changed when searching. My URL looks like `?s=abstract+pattern&post_type=product` and the query used is

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.*, ID, (MATCH(post_title) AGAINST ('abstract pattern' ) * 1 ) + (MATCH(post_content) AGAINST ('abstract pattern' ) * 10 ) AS score 
FROM wp_posts 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta
ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id )
WHERE 1=1 
AND MATCH (post_title,post_content) AGAINST ('abstract pattern' ) 
AND (post_status = 'publish'
OR post_status = 'inherit')
AND wp_posts.post_type IN ('product') 
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
ORDER BY score DESC 
LIMIT 0, 12
```

Comment: Try using an array as format instead.

Comment: https://make.wordpress.org/core/2014/08/29/a-more-powerful-order-by-in-wordpress-4-0/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that I had a plugin installed that deals with the searches, it's called Better Search.

```
function query_1($query){
    $query .= ",wp_postmeta.meta_value as total_saless ";
    return $query;
}
add_filter( 'bsearch_posts_match_field', 'query_1' );

function query_2($query){
    $query .= "AND wp_postmeta.meta_key='total_sales' ";
    return $query;
}
add_filter( 'bsearch_posts_where', 'query_2' );

function query_3($query){
    $query = " CAST(total_saless AS INTEGER) > 99999 DESC, score DESC ";
    return $query;
}
add_filter( 'bsearch_posts_orderby', 'query_3' );
```

All I had to do was to hook into it.